# Progressive bar service in Vue

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I am learning Vue after working for some time with Angular and I'd like to hear experienced programmers concerning the implementation of my Progressive Bar service *(in Vue it's called Plugin)*.

The idea behind it is to have a solid service which is responsible for the progress bar indicator.

I've got there a component with the logic for displaying and hiding and CSS with HTML Mark-up. And the core which serves as a middleware (or a service in Angular) between the component and Providers *(vueRouter and Apollo)*.

I wasn't sure if it's a good practice to use RxJS in Vue. I've always thought that it's reactive itself but here I found it useful to have it. Is it a good practice?

It's still raw. Later on I'd like to make it customizable with options, but for now I'd like to know if I'm on the right way.

main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRx from 'vue-rx'
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import { createProvider } from './vue-apollo'

import ProgressBar from '@/plugins/progressBarPlugin';

Vue.use(ProgressBar);
Vue.use(VueRx)

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

export default new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  apolloProvider: createProvider(),
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

index.js (progressBarPlugin)

```
import ProgressBarComponent from './progress-bar/progress-bar.vue';
import apolloHook from './apolloHook.js';
import vueRouterHook from './vueRouterHook.js';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs'
import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators'

export const state = new Subject().pipe(distinctUntilChanged());

const ProgressBarPlugin = {
    install(Vue) {
        Vue.component(ProgressBarComponent.name, ProgressBarComponent);

        Vue.mixin({
            created() {
                if (this.$options.name === ProgressBarComponent.name) {
                    apolloHook(state, this.$apolloProvider);
                    vueRouterHook(state, this.$router)
                }

            }
        })
    },

    request() {
        state.next('request');
    },

    response() {
        state.next('response');
    },

    done() {
        state.next('done');
    }
};

export default ProgressBarPlugin;
```

apolloHook

```
export default function apollo(state, apolloProvider) {
    if (apolloProvider) {

        apolloProvider.watchLoading = function (loading) {
            // This function can also accept param counter: -1 / 1

            (loading) ? state.next('request') : state.next('done');

        };

    }
}
```

vueRouterHook

```
export default function vueRouter(state, router) {
    if (router) {
        router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
            state.next('request');
            next();
            state.next('response');
        })

        router.afterEach(() => {
            state.next('done');
        })

    }
}
```